# Logger levels algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, logging

I should create method which get as parameters `(String logMessage,String level)`  . There is also parameter for logger -SetLogLevel. Possible levels are low, medium, high.

- If SetLogLevel==low, logs output should include all messages with all levels.
- If SetLogLevel==medium, logs output should include all messages with levels like medium || high.
- If SetLogLevel==high, only messages with "high" levels should be outputed.

Any idea? Can it be implemented in only one method? I can implement such method in way when for example SetLogLevel==medium, only medium levels are outputted..but I can't figured out how to do it in described above way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum LoggerLevel {
    Low(0), Medium(1), High(2);

    private int value;
    public LoggerLevel(int val) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public void log (String mes, LoggerLevel lvl) {
    if (lvl.getValue() >= getLoggingLevel().getValue()) {
        // logic here
    }
}
```

Edit : I had written it like in C#. In java, enums are not integers, they are objects.

Comment: Check the edit. I had written it like I would've written it in C#, because I witch constantly between the two languages lol. In C#, enums can only extend integer types.